# Web Applications Converted To Desktop Applications

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications, desktop-application

I have been reading some of the posts here, but haven't really seen the answers to my questions directly.  I am a web developer and need to integrate some of my web applications to some sort of desktop application.  For example, say a business has some kind of booking, it needs to be available offline (desktop in office/stores) and online, with the master database offline.  What I would like to know is the best way in doing something like this and different options.  If I can use web technology like PHP/MySQL and then use something like WinBinder to be able to handle all the work, then great, but from my research, I get the impression this is not a great approach.  PHP/MySQL is what I mainly use for backend development, however know some other languages, just haven't mastered them yet.

Can you guys suggest some methods of acheiving what I need and what languages, etc are the best?  Can I stick with web technologies, but create simple install packages so clients can install the application easily?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Great question.  Wrong venue.  ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discourage to use PHP as desktop application.

You should sepearte the 2 appliaction.

- Web app using PHP
- Desktop app using Java (or whatever you want)

In your desktop app you should provide a "journaled" system that can save all the actions users make offline and upload it when the users go online (or when the users want) to your PHP application so you can push those actions in your DB.

Comment: Can you tell me why you discourage PHP as desktop?  I do understand it is probably not the best approach, but would like to know why.  Would you suggest Java as the desktop application, so I would look for a Java Developer?

Comment: @fanfavorite: the answer is simple: PHP isn't made for desktop standalone application. It's great for web development not for desktop,

Comment: @dynamic PHP was not initially designed to be a desktop programming language but at the end of the day lots of powerful websites are powered by PHP (e.g. Facebook). This proves that PHP can also be used for Desktop programs. Now, obviously the problem is PHP cannot be yet compiled but "PHP Nightrain" is going to change all that. You already can do a lot with PHP Nightrain but once the feature to compile your HTML, PHP, CSS sources kicks in, it will change everything. Take a look at this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GXt8erPLf4o

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need a Rich Internet Application.  Here is a good explanation.

http://searchsoa.techtarget.com/definition/Rich-Internet-Application-RIA

Microsoft Silverlight has one of the best offerings because they can run integrated within a web page as well as a desktop application.

Java Web Start and Flash are similar offerrings as well.

EDIT: I just want to say that PHP is all kinds of wrong for this type of solution.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer was great as well, wanted to accept both your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Today, with the new browsers, you can store a local db inside the browser like you store a cookie,
my suggestion is to take some nice ui web framework like [sproutecore](http://www.sproutcore.com/) or if you like php go for [jqm](http://www.jqm1.com/2011/05/jqmphp/) php, and use it as desktop app, check the offline features that the frameworks offer before you start.